# Python ical start time

Tags: python, calendar, icalendar

Here is my problem, I'm using Icalendar on Python to parse data from 2 ical file and one excel file (xls).
Problem, when I try to get my calendar (using this):

```
    for event in cal.walk('vevent'):
        dates = event.get('dtstart')
        location = event.get('location')
        dates=dates.to_ical()
        month=dates[4:6]
        day=dates[6:8]
        heures2=dates[9:11]
        minut=dates[11:13]
        sec=dates[13:15]
        yearical=dates[0:4]
        date2=day+"/"+month+"/"+yearical
        summary = event.get('summary')
        icaldebheur = heures2+":"+minut+":"+sec
```

The problem is that my ical file look like this:
[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtTEK.png)
The only hour that the code give me are the 8H one and 13h30one (observed by doing a print icaldebheur), no matter the day, it never give me the one at 10H (or, if it happen the afternoon, it don't give me one at 15H).
It seem like it only give me 2 event per day.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you have to be aware of when dealing with iCalendar files is **timezones**.

- If the date/time property value ends in `Z`, that means the time is
  formatted in **UTC time**.
- If the date/time property has a `TZID`
  parameter, that means the date/time value is formatted in a **specific
  timezone**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already manage time (stocking time in variable and after comparing it to my others files), my problem is that when I have 2 event in the morning (between 8H and 12H) the program only show me the first. I don't see how time-zones are involved in that. Am I missing something?